# Postgres ERROR:duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: postgresql

Table defintion is

```
create table users (
serial_no integer PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('serial'),
uid bigint NOT NULL,
username varchar(32),
name text,
CONSTRAINT production UNIQUE(uid)
);
```

I used this query

```
INSERT INTO users (uid) values(123) ;
```

It says duplicate key value violates unique constraint. So I googled it and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-postgresql)

So I tried

```
INSERT INTO users (uid) values(123) 
where 1 in (select 1 from users where uid = 123) ;
```

It says yntax error at or near "WHERE".

How to use a statement of insert into using the where clause so that when I run the same query using php it does not return an error

column uid is unique

Comment: What is the table definition? The error message seems pretty darn clear. It looks like there is a unique constraint on the table that is preventing you from inserting more than 1 row with a `uid = 123`.

Comment: There's already a row with a uid of 123. The database is behaving correctly. What's your question?

Comment: If you execute this query, `select count(*) from users where uid = 123;`, what do you get?

Comment: @AnubhavAgarwal: So you already have one row with a unique uid of 123. Why are you trying to insert two such rows, and what do you want to happen when you try to violate a unique constraint?

Comment: Postgres folks are unfriendly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [INSERT statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-insert.html) doesn't support a WHERE clause. Run this.

```
create table test (
  n integer primary key
);

insert into test values (1);
insert into test values (2) where true;
```

That will give you a syntax error because of the WHERE clause.

SELECT statements can have a WHERE clause, though.  This will insert 2 into the test table one time. Run it as many times as you want; it won't raise an error. (But it will insert only one row at the most.)

```
insert into test (n) 
select 2 where 2 not in (select n from test where n = 2);
```

So your query, assuming you're trying to avoid raising an error on a duplicate key, should be something like this.

```
INSERT INTO users (uid) 
SELECT 123 WHERE 123 not in (SELECT uid FROM users WHERE uid = 123) ;
```